# spring QuartzJobBean set frequency

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring boot app,my scheduler class as follows up.
Problem is, it runs every one minute.
how do i schedule it to run every 1 hour instead of every1 minute?

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

public class ApplicationPendingConsentJob extends QuartzJobBean {

}
```

Comment: By providing the proper cron expression, which you now probably have for every minute. WIthout knowing how you schedule these things this will be impossible to know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Quartz job by implementing the org.quartz.Job interface. This interface requires you to implement the execute() method, which contains the logic to be executed by the job.

```
public class MyJob implements Job {
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    // Your job logic goes here
 }
}
```

Configure the job and trigger in a Quartz configuration class using the @Configuration annotation. Define a SchedulerFactoryBean bean and set the job and trigger details.

```
 @Configuration
 public class QuartzConfig {
// Define your job
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobClass(MyJob.class);
    return factory;
}

// Define your trigger
@Bean
public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean simpleTriggerFactoryBean() {
    SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factory = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
    factory.setRepeatInterval(60000); // Repeat every 60 seconds
    return factory;
}

// Define the scheduler
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setTriggers(simpleTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return factory;
 }
}
```